# Passing interface to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle

Let's consider a case where I have `Fragment A` and `Fragment B`.

`B` declares:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void onTrigger(int position);
}
```

`A` implements this interface.

When pushing `Fragment B` into stack, how should I pass reference of `Fragment A` for it in `Bundle` so `A` can get the `onTrigger` callback when needed.

My use case scenario is that `A` has `ListView` with items and `B` has `ViewPager` with items. Both contain same items and when user goes from `B -> A` before popping `B` it should trigger the callback for `A` to update it's `ListView` position to match with `B` pager position.

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
Passing interface to Fragment
```

I think you are communicating between two `Fragment`

In order to do so, you can have a look into [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment{
    MyInterface mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface MyInterface {
        public void onTrigger();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (MyInterface ) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement MyInterface ");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: But my Activity has nothing to do with the two Fragments which wan't to communicate, isn't there any other solution?

Comment: @Niko can you explain bit more with some user interface. So that i can help you out.

Comment: Updated my question with the use case.

Comment: The link to the Android Docs helped me to complete this

Answer (score 6):

For Kotlin 1.0.0-beta-3595

```
interface SomeCallback {}

class SomeFragment() : Fragment(){

    var callback : SomeCallback? = null //some might want late init, but I think this way is safer

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        callback = activity as? SomeCallback //returns null if not type 'SomeCallback'

        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.frag_some_view, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is optimal for two fragments to only communicate through an activity. So you can define an interface in Fragment B that is implemented in the activity. Then in the activity, define in the interface method what you want to happen in fragment A.

In Fragment B,

```
MyInterface mCallback;
 public interface MyInterface {
        void onTrigger(int position);
    }

@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (MyInterface) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement MyInterface");
        }
}
```

Method for determining if user goes from B to A

```
public void onChangeFragment(int position){
//other logic here
 mCallback.onTrigger(position);
}
```

In Activity,

```
public void onTrigger(int position) {
    //Find listview in fragment A
    listView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
    }
```

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Using @Amit's answer, and adapting to the OPs question, here is all the relevant code:

```
public class FragmentA extends BaseFragment implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE OF WHERE YOU MIGHT CREATE FragmentB
        FragmentB myFragmentB = new FragmentB();        
    }


    void onTrigger(int position){
        // My Callback Happens Here!
    }
}
```

...

```
public class FragmentB extends BaseFragment {

    private MyInterface callback;

    public interface MyInterface {
        void onTrigger(int position);
    }   

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            callback = (MyInterface ) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement MyInterface");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did the same but didn't get the callback in Fragment A but I got the callback in Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use communication, as I've written below. This code comes from [this Android Dev page of communication between Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating):

**HeadlinesFragment**

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

public void setOnHeadlineSelectedListener(Activity activity) {
    mCallback = activity;
}

// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
    public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}

// ...
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
// ...

@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment instanceof HeadlinesFragment) {
        HeadlinesFragment headlinesFragment = (HeadlinesFragment) fragment;
        headlinesFragment.setOnHeadlineSelectedListener(this);
    }
}

public static class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
...

public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment
    // Do something here to display that article
}
```

Comment: Rather than linking, it would be more helpful to include the most relevant parts as a quoted block in your answer, and provide the link as a reference

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver I did so

Comment: Ah, the code **is** the quote. Then perhaps your first line should be: "I think you should use communication, as I've written below. This code comes from [this Android Dev page on communication](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating)"

Answer (score 0):

You may create call back interface by this way.

```
 var screenVisibility=activity as YourActivity
 screenVisibility.setScreenVisibility("which screen you want")
```